# How to delete file inside folder in another directory with PHP

Tags: php, delete-file

I'm new to PHP. I want to delete a file from a folder in the parent of my path. I tried to do this with 'unlink' but failed.

How can I delete the '1.mp3' file in the admin/Records/mp3 folder while working on the index.php page, as in the image below.

[image: folders]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You are missing some context here. I assume you are in a web page, running inside a web server like Apache, so it would be good to add that to your question.

Comment: It looks like your `index.php` is at the root of your project, so you could just do `$projectRoot = realpath(__DIR__);` to get the full pathname of the root, and then add the rest of the directories + filename to that.

Answer (score 1):

Code:

```
unlink('../admin/Records/mp3/1.mp3');
```